# What is the literal translation of 比尔 • 盖茨每年都要进行两次为期一周的 “闭关”？

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

从20世纪80年代起，比尔 • 盖茨每年都要进行两次为期一周的 “闭关” 。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK 5, chapter 26.

I want your help in the literal translation of this: 比尔 • 盖茨每年都要进行两次为期一周的 “闭关” 。

I have reached on this point: 比尔 • 盖茨(Bill Gates)每年(every year)都要进行两次为期(??)一周(one week)的 “闭关” (seclusion).

As you can see I cannot understand this 都要进行两次为期

都：Is it just an emphatic character?

要：I know it means to want or will. But here?

进行：Does it mean to conduct? To carry out?

两次：Does it mean twice?

为期: Does it mean deadline?

How to make all this make sense here?

Answer (score 1):

为期一周 is a phrase that is the modifier of 闭关.

两次 = twice

为期一周 = each time lasting one week

闭关 = seclusion

> 都：Is it just an emphatic character?

Yes.

> 要：I know it means to want or will. But here?

Both. It's a weak modality. From the viewpoint of an external observer, since the sentence describes a regular event, one can interpret this 要 as epistemic modality. Since the event is also something that Bill Gates voluntarily does, one can also interpret this as a weak deontic modality.

> 进行：Does it mean to conduct? To carry out?

Yes.

> 两次：Does it mean twice?

Yes.

> 为期: Does it mean deadline?

为期 + duration is a formal way to describe the length of an event. Colloquially 为期 is omitted, leaving only 一周的闭关, hence your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

比尔 • 盖茨每年都要进行两次为期一周的 “闭关” 。- Twice every year, Bill Gates will always go on a week-long seclusion.

Answer (score 0):

比尔 • 盖茨(Bill Gates)每年(every year)都要(always needs (to))进行(undergo)两次(two times)为期(for a duration of)一周(one week)的 “闭关”(seclusion)

Answer (score 0):

没 ... 都: every, all
要进行: will carry out
两次为期一周: 2 times as period 1 week
闭关: seclusion (digital detox)

比尔 • 盖茨
Bill Gates
每年都
every year
要进行
practices
两次为期一周的 “闭关” 。
a week of seclusion two times.

比尔 • 盖茨每年都要进行两次为期一周的 “闭关” 。
Bill Gates carries out a week of seclusion twice every year.

Answer (score 0):

**比尔 • 盖茨**  (每年都要)  **进行**  (两次为期一周的)   “**闭关**” 。

比尔 • 盖茨进行“闭关” 。

---

**每年都要**: 每年都会怎样怎样. eg: 我每天(睡前)都会听歌.

**两次**: mean twice, 修饰 闭关, 结合上面, 每年都会有两次的 闭关

**为期一周**: 为期(约束一段时间) 修饰一周.

- 如:

  - 五日为期(deadline, 名词). 五日为期, 过期不候
  - 为期三天: (可做形容词)为期三天的会议; 为期三天, xxx举行春节庆祝活动.

> When I was learning English, I first used an English-Chinese dictionary. Since I started using an English-English dictionary(cambridge or collins), I have been able to learn more things.
> English dictionaries use simple words to explain complex words

Answer (score 0):

闭关: solitude

Bill Gates seeks a week-long solitude twice a year.